# make "fit to screen" default window size in Quicktime

Tags: applescript, quicktime

How can I make Quicktime to always open in Fit to Screen option (available at View->Fit to Screen)? It doesn't seem to remember the last window size.

Is it possible to attach a script to a program, so that every time the program launches, the attached script executes? In my case, it would change the window size to Fit to Screen

Comment: Don't know if you had already looked at my answer however I wanted to let you know that I've updated it a couple of times so you may want to look at it again if you had already looked earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**QuickTime Player** doesn't have a **Preferences...** *menu command* like other applications do, nor does it have a *com.apple.quicktime.plist* file to manipulate. Therefore there isn't anything you can do directly, however here is a workaround of sorts.

Note that this workaround requires changing the *default* application for *file types*, e.g. *.mov*, you'd normally open directly with **QuickTime Player** to the application created herein, called: **QTP Fit to Screen.app**

Using **Automator** create a new *Application* and add a **Run Shell Script** *Action*.

Change: **Pass input: [to stdin]** *to* **[as argument]**

Add the following *code*:

```
if [[ ! -z $1 ]]; then

    open -a "QuickTime Player" "$1"

    osascript -e 'tell application "QuickTime Player" to activate' \
              -e 'delay 1' \
              -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "3" using command down' \
              -e 'tell application "QuickTime Player" to play front document'
fi
```

[image]

Save it as an *Application* named: **QTP Fit to Screen**

In order for **QTP Fit to Screen** to be the *global default app* for, e.g. *.mov*, files you'd open in QuickTime Player you'll have to use the **Default Apps** Preference Pane, [RCDefaultApp by Rubicode](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) to change which application opens a given Extension.

Install **RCDefaultApp** and then in **System Preferences** > **Default Apps** select the **Extensions** tab and scroll down to ***mov*** and then change the **Default Application:** *to*: **QTP Fit to Screen**

Now then you double-click *.mov* files in **Finder** or accessing them from **Spotlight** the **QTP Fit to Screen** application will open the target file in **Quick Time Player**, set **View** to **Fit to Screen** and start playing the file.

Note: If you do not want it to automatically start playing the file then remove the line of *code*, the one that has "play front document" in it.

If you need modify other *default* methods of file types, Apps, URLs, UTIs, etc. the **Default Apps** Preference Pane, [RCDefaultApp by Rubicode](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/), is a great utility for it.

To make the **QTP Fit to Screen.app** application bundle look better in the Applications folder you can copy and paste the **QuickTime Player.app** application icon from its **Get Info** *sheet* to the icon of the **Get Info** *sheet* for **QTP Fit to Screen.app**.

---

Note: I added the `if` *statement* to the *code* so the **QTP Fit to Screen** application doesn't error out when executed by itself.  In other words, double-clicking it will essentially do nothing, whereas without it will throw a couple of error messages.

Comment: daaaamn, Apple really doesnt like QTPlayer. Thank you, kind sir!